# Guest User access to Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce communities

Tags: community, force.com-sites

So i have a requirement in which i have to provide 100 users access to Salesforce knowledge (read only) without having to create users for them in the org itself (to save license cost). In order to achieve the same i opted for creating a community. The template i chose was Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce and added Knowledge tab to it. I provided the required access to the guest user profiel:
1. Tab - default on
2. Read permission to article types
3. Made articles public

Now, when i try to access the communty url when logged in it looks good but when i try to access as guest user it takes me to login page instead of directly logging me in. What am i missing?

View when logged in:
[image]

View as guest user:

[image]

Comment: You should make your community public in the settings.

Comment: I do not see that option. This template does not have experience builder like other community templates.